# Beautiful soup looping through array of URLs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to loop through an array of URLs and scrape board members from a list of companies. There seems to be a problem with my loop below, where it's only running the first element in the array and duplicating results. Any help with this would be appreciated. Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#array of URLs to loop through, will be larger once I get the loop working correctly
tickers = ['http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=AAPL.O', 'http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=GOOG.O']

board_members = []
output = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for t in tickers:
    html = requests.get(t).text
    officer_table = soup.find('table', {"class" : "dataTable"})
    for row in officer_table.find_all('tr'):
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        if len(cols) == 4:
            board_members.append((t, cols[0].text.strip(), cols[1].text.strip(), cols[2].text.strip(), cols[3].text.strip()))

        for t, name, age, year_joined, position in board_members:
            output.append(('{} {:35} {} {} {}'.format(t, name, age, year_joined, position)))
```

Comment: This code shouldn't run. `BeautifulSoup(html` will error that `html` is not defined

Comment: Anyways, consider storing just the symbols in the list. Format the URL later when you make the request

Answer (score 1):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for t in tickers:
    html = requests.get(t).text
    officer_table = soup.find('table', {"class" : "dataTable"})
```

you put soup out of the for loop, this will cause a error, because the 'html' dose not exist when you use `BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")`
just put it in the loop after html is assigned.

```
for t in tickers:
    html = requests.get(t).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    officer_table = soup.find('table', {"class" : "dataTable"})
```